# Can you copy (download) a file that is currently open?

Tags: python, files, filesystem, data-corruption

I am currently generating a large file on our Ubuntu server. A Python process has the file handle open and is continuously writing new lines (JSONL) to it. My, perhaps obvious to some, question is whether I can download that file to my own device without that leading to issues (e.g., the Python process crashing or a corrupted file)? I know I can just try it, but I do not want to take that risk.

As far as I can tell, there is no hidden/`lock` file in the file system so my assumption is that it is safe. I'd also be interested to know more about general use-case: when is it safe to copy a file and when isn't it (if ever)?

Comment: Possible != Safe

Comment: Your question is not about Ubuntu. General programming questions are better placed at stackoverflow.com. However, if you open the file for reading only, there won't be any issues for the process writing to the file. The last line might be incomplete though for the reading process.

Comment: @pLumo How is this not specific to Ubuntu? It definitely is! I'd expect different answers for different OS's. What may work on Ubuntu may not work on Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As copying does not involve changing the file, it will likely not disrupt the ongoing process. "Copying" the file to another Ubuntu system may be "safe" in the sense that you will copy the data that was there when you started the copy. Any data added during the copy will not be included.